# Accessing Vue data objects in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I just switched from plain JavaScript to Typescript (or at least I'm trying to). Here is code that worked perfectly just before, minus the typing done so far:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
        name: "Index",
        data() {
            return {
                years: Array,
                bgs: Array
            }
        },
        methods: {
            loadYears: function (): void {
                let self = this;
                axios.get('../letter/get/years').then(function (response) {
                    function pushYears(value: any) {
                        self.years.push(value);

                    }

                    response.data['years'].forEach(pushYears);
                });
            },
            loadBg: function (): void {
                let self = this;
                axios.get('../bg/get/all').then(function (response) {
                    JSON.parse(response.data['bgs']).forEach(function (obj: any) {
                        self.bgs.push(obj);
                    })
                });
            }
        },
        beforeMount() {
            this.loadYears();
            this.loadBg();
        }
    }
</script>
```

now after switching to Typescript, self.years.push(value) and self.bgs.push(obj) are not working anymore, the corresponding errors says: "self.$data.years.push is not a function".
Interestingly enough, in the beforeMount()-function I get an error saying that loadYears() and loadBg are not defined, but accessing the data()-objects works perfectly in this block via this.data().years or bgs. How can I access these properties inside my methods-block?

Comment: can you share your exact typescript code. Typescript in vue is quite a bit different than vanilla js

Comment: You basically saw everything, this is my whole <script>-Tag now

Comment: Use composition API. The syntax you're using isn't intended for easy typing. See https://vue-composition-api-rfc.netlify.com/api.html . `bgs: Array` - this is a mistake, this is not TS typing, you basically assign Array constructor, this is the reason why push is not a function.

Comment: see also [vue typescript guide](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html), it isn't a 1 to 1 transition from js to ts

Answer (score 2):

you have two ways to `type` yours data properties as bellow:

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';

interface Model {
  name: string
  age: number
}

export default Vue.extend({    
  data () {
    const foo: Model[] = [];
    return {
      foo,
      bar: [] as Model[]
    };
  },

  mounted () {
    this.foo.push({
      name: 'user', age: 22
    });
    this.bar.push({
      name: 'guest', age: 20
    });
  },
});
</script>
```